# For only one function, how to change wordpress php code timezone from UTC to my local?

Tags: php, wordpress

I added this code to my `functions.php` from stack overflow to manage my upload folder by `date (2019/08/14)` instead of by `month`

```
function upload_dir_filter($uploads){
  $day = date('d');
  $uploads['path'] .= '/' . $day;
  $uploads['url']  .= '/' . $day;
return $uploads;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir_filter');
```

Then month change, I got a folder on `31 August 2019`. Instead of `31 July 2019`. I realize that this code is using UTC even though I set my VPS to `Australia/Melbourne` time.

I already change the `timezone` in the WordPress admin (via web browser) but no effect

How do I change WordPress PHP code timezone?

Note: I leave date.timezone in PHP blank (or didn't set it to anything at all) because default `VPS timezone` is already `Australia/Melbourne`

Edit:
After some thought, the wordpress and bundles (php, etc.) setting is correct because my timezone is UTC+10 (ahead of GMT)

The time are already in August 1 but this particular code is stuck in July 31.

How do I set timezone for this particular code only? Is this correct? - not affecting timezone in other codes?

```
function upload_dir_filter($uploads){
  date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
  $day = date('d'); -----> Only want this to return in 'Australia/Melbourne' time without affecting other or general wordpress setting
  $uploads['path'] .= '/' . $day;
  $uploads['url']  .= '/' . $day;
return $uploads;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir_filter');
```

Comment: add `date_default_timezone_set("zone_name");` in top of `index.php`

Comment: I don't want to do this in index.php because it is risky. I just want this particular code to return `date` in defined timezone. Is the above correct?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57195/is-it-safe-to-use-date-default-timezone-set-in-plugin-file